# Validate Collection using JSR 303

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

I want to validate array of beans using JSR 303 Validation. Like [spec](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e416) says, it's possible to validate the whole collection.
if I had object like this

```
public class Car {
  @NotNull
  @Valid
  private List<Person> passengers = new ArrayList<Person>();
}
```

so I would be able to validate list of passengers by doing following:

```
Car car = ....
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> validation = validator.validate(car);
```

But I wondering, why can't I validate list of passengers by doing following:

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<List<Person>>> validation =validator.validate(passengers);
```

It just doesn't work! Can anybody give me any explanations on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bean Validation doesn't offer an API for directly validating collections. Only the cascaded validation of collections/arrays using `@Valid` is supported.

The `validate()` method you're using validates the constraints declared on the type of the passed object. There are no constraints declared on `List` or `ArrayList`, that's why no constraint violations occure when passing a list directly to `validate()`.

You could either iterate over the passenger list and validate the individual elements or validate a object owning the list (as in your original example).